# Clojure, Java interop: how to get File.separator?

Tags: java, clojure, interop

Somehow I can't access the path component separator character: File.separator, according to lore. These are my current imports:

```
(ns pcc.core
  (:require [me.raynes.fs :as fs])
  (:import java.io.File)
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:require [clojure.string :as string])
  (:require [clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])
  (:gen-class))
```

Probably can't hit the right syntax.

Comment: Do you even need File/separator if you're using raynes.fs? It's supposed to handle building those File objects for you. eg, instead of something like `(file (str dir File/separator filename))`, you should just use `(file dir filename)`, and fs will insert the appropriate separator.

Answer (score 8):

To access static fields, use the `/` character:

```
user=> (java.io.File/separator)
"/"
```